# How to Suspend a button event in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, suspend

In my application I want to suspend a button event for some time so that I can fire another event after which the first button event will resume. In c# I am not getting how do I perform it using threads asynchronously. Please help. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fire the second event and wait for it to finish before continuing, then why not just fire it *synchronously* from within the first event handler?  That would be much simpler.

#### EDIT:

If you want one button to trigger the code that's in another button's event handler, I would suggest instead that you move it out into a separate function, and just call that.  In other words, do this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoButtonStuff();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoButtonStuff();
}

private void DoButtonStuff()
{
    // code that was originally in button2_Click()
}
```

If the buttons do the exact same thing, you could even just assign them the exact same handler.

But, if you really must programmatically "click" a button, then the easiest way is probably:

```
button2.PerformClick();
```

That'll raise a `Click` event.

Comment: ya iam trying to do that I need some sample code for that. I need to know how to fire a button event within other event. But I dont know the parameters of the button event please provide sample code

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a design problem in your application and you're tackling it from the wrong end.

Answer (score 0):

could you do something with background worker

```
background worker bw = new background worker


button1

while bw.inprogress
{

//kill time

}
bw.(dosomething)



button2
{
while bw.inprogress
{
//killtime

}
bw.run(dosomething)
}
```